# Iterative queries

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, iteration, hierarchy

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_example
(
    column_1 int,
    column_2 int,
    column_3 int,
    column_4 int);
```

Inserting values

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO tbl_example (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) VALUES (99,10,10,10)
  INTO tbl_example (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) VALUES (10,99,10,10)
  INTO tbl_example (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4) VALUES (10,10,10,10)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

[image: Results]

My Query

```
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3
FROM tbl_example where column_1 = '99'
UNION ALL
SELECT column_1,column_2,column_3
FROM tbl_example where column_2 = '99';
```

[image]

I want to optimize the query without using a procedure, so I need two things:

1. Run an iterative "Select" from "column_1" to "column_3"
2. Do the same in "Where" clause

Is that possible?

Comment: please update your question to include sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Variable set of columns ... Go dynamic apparently  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: `where 99 in (column_1, column_2, column_3)`?